# Count of individual items entered via a validation drop-down

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, excel-2007, countif

I have a drop-down list to populate cells in a column and want to count the instances of each selected value. Considering the image below, I would like to get the sum of Pizza, Pancakes and Chinese. I'm using MS Office 2007.

For 45 rows the required result might be:  Pizza choices = 10, Pancakes choices = 35.

Can we use SUMIF formula with indexes?

[image: SO26229115 question example]

Comment: The drop down is applicable for complete B column. I want to get the sum of Pizza, Pancakes, Chinese in seperate cell. Like Total Pizza choices = 10, Total Pancakes choices = 35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your validation list were say in ColumnF starting in Row1 then maybe what you want is:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,F1)
```

copied down to suit.